# Write and equation and justification to find $x$.

Tags: geometry, angle

I'm a little stuck on the following question, help would be appreciated

Given that $m\angle ABD=2x+12$, $m\angle CBD= 6x-18$, and $BD$ is an angle bisector, write an equation and justification to find $x$.

[image]

Comment: Does $\text{m}\measuredangle ABD =\text{m}\measuredangle CBD$ hold?

Comment: What other information do you have?

Comment: You already have two equations.  Unless you have other information, there is no third equation.

Comment: This is all the information that I received. Btw BD is a bisector.

Comment: I think that the “justification” that a high-school teacher is looking for is the remark that the bisector divides the big angle into two *equal* smaller angles, $\angle ABD$ and $\angle DBC$.

Comment: *Btw BD is a bisector*.  So you did *not* originally provide us will all the information you received.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that $BD$ is a bisector, then $2x+12 = 6x-18 \implies 4x = 30 \implies x = \dfrac{15}{2}$.

Comment: How do I "Justify" this?

Comment: It is just by definition of the problem. Unless there is any other information about the angular measure of $\angle{ABC}$ or if $BD$ is an angle bisector this is only answer.